# Send e-mail in using C#

Tags: c#, mailmessage

The code shown below is how I am trying to send an email. But I receive an error `Failure sending mail`,

Can anyone tell what is problem happening here?

```
            MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
            SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient("Smtp1.ajmanchamber.ae");
            mail.From = new MailAddress("Coo-services@ajmanchamber.ae");
            mail.To.Add(mailId);
            mail.Subject = "New COO Request Created";
            mail.Body = "New COO Request is created and your Reference Number is " + ReferenceNo;
            SmtpServer.Port = 587;
            SmtpServer.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("user", "pasword");
            SmtpServer.EnableSsl = true;
            SmtpServer.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
            SmtpServer.Send(mail);
```

when i change the code and  try it this way i get

```
            MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
            SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient("Smtp1.ajmanchamber.ae");
            mail.From = new MailAddress("Coo-services@ajmanchamber.ae");
            mail.To.Add(mailId);
            mail.Subject = "New COO Request Created";
            mail.Body = "New COO Request is created and your Reference Number is " + ReferenceNo;
            SmtpServer.Port = 25;
            SmtpServer.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
            SmtpServer.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("user", "password");
            SmtpServer.EnableSsl = true;
            SmtpServer.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
            SmtpServer.Send(mail);
```

i get this error The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.

Comment: Either use `DefaultCredentials = true` or `new NetworkCredential(...)` both together won't work

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: still receiving the same error Failure Sending Mail

Comment: @user3300517 check with code answered by me.Hope it helps you

Answer (score 1):

try this one

```
MailMessage message = new MailMessage();
SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();

message.From = new MailAddress("EmailId");
message.To.Add(new MailAddress("ReceiverEmailId"));
message.Subject = "auto generated mail";
message.Body = "Hello world";
smtp.Port = 25;

smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";

smtp.EnableSsl = true;
smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("EmailId", "Password");
smtp.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
smtp.Send(message);
```

Comment: i get this error The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.

Comment: @user3300517  put this code somewere before `smtpclient.Send():`   to switch off certificate validation==>

    `ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate(object s, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors) { return true; };`

Comment: @user3300517 but this code is working perfectly fine in my project

Answer (score 0):

Replace `mail.To.Add(mailId);` with

```
mail.To = new MailAddress("example@domain.com");
```

I don't understand why you used `SmtpServer.UseDefaultCredentials = true;` and `SmtpServer.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("user", "pasword");` at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com");

mail.From = new MailAddress("me@mydomain.com");
mail.To.Add("u@urdomain.com");
mail.Subject = filename;
mail.Body = "Report";
Attachment attachment = new Attachment(filename);
mail.Attachments.Add(attachment);

SmtpServer.Port = 25;
SmtpServer.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("me", "password");
SmtpServer.EnableSsl = true;

SmtpServer.Send(mail);
```

Comment: when trying this i get error Mailbox unavailable. The server response was: 5.7.1 Unable to relay

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this

```
 MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
 SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient("Smtp1.ajmanchamber.ae");
 mail.From = new MailAddress("Coo-services@ajmanchamber.ae");
 mail.To.Add(mailId);
 mail.Subject = "New COO Request Created";
 mail.Body = "New COO Request is created and your Reference Number is " + ReferenceNo;
 SmtpServer.Port = 587;
 SmtpServer.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
 SmtpServer.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("user", "pasword");
 SmtpServer.EnableSsl = false;
 SmtpServer.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
 SmtpServer.Send(mail);
```

and if you `Enable Ssl,the Port is 465`.

Comment: getting this error Failure sending mail at  SmtpServer.Send(mail)

Comment: The default post for ssl is 465.if you don't want to enable ssl make it false and use port 587 or 25.check this http://www.arclab.com/en/amlc/list-of-smtp-and-pop3-servers-mailserver-list.html

Comment: Dont use port and Check this. MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
 SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient("Smtp1.ajmanchamber.ae");
 mail.From = new MailAddress("Coo-services@ajmanchamber.ae");
 mail.To.Add(mailId);
 mail.Subject = "New COO Request Created";
 mail.Body = "New COO Request is created and your Reference Number is " + ReferenceNo;
 SmtpServer.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
 SmtpServer.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("user", "pasword");
 SmtpServer.EnableSsl = false;
 SmtpServer.Send(mail);